# Getting error "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

Getting error "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"  in selenium java. I have read the reason for this error to come but don't know in which line in my code causing these errors to come. I am new to automation so don't know which line need to be corrected.  Here is my code:

```
///////This is the class where my test case is being executed.
public class LoginTestCase extends ExtentReportBaseClass  {

    static WebDriver driver;
    //Homepage login = new Homepage();
    UtilityMethods util = new UtilityMethods();
    configFileReader configReaderObj=new configFileReader();

    String locUsernameElem;
    String locPasswordelem;
    String Sign_in;
    String insertEmail;
    String insertFirstName;
    String createAccountButton;    

    // @Parameters("browser")

    @BeforeClass
    public void launchBrowser() {

        driver= UtilityMethods.openBrowser(ConstantsValues.BROWSER_NAME);

        UtilityMethods.launchWebsite(Utility.ConstantsValues.URL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //report = ExtentReportBaseClass.setUp();
    }

    @Test
    public void registration() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        test = report.createTest("registration", "This will check status for registration of the user.");
        Sign_in = Utility.UtilityLocatorz.SignUp.SIGN_IN;
        reportLog("User will create a new account");
        createAccountButton = Utility.UtilityLocatorz.SignUp.CREATE_ACOUNT;
        util.clickElement(Sign_in);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        reportLog("User will put his personal details");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email_create")).sendKeys("vivek443333111@gmail.com");
        //util.sendData(insertEmail);
        util.clickElement(UtilityLocatorz.SignUp.CREATE_ACCOUNT);

        util.clickElement(UtilityLocatorz.SignUp.USER_TITLE);
        reportLog("User will add personal details for his new account");
        util.sendDataById("customer_firstname", UtilityLocatorz.SignUp.FIRST_NAME);
        util.sendDataById("customer_lastname", UtilityLocatorz.SignUp.LAST_NAME);
        util.sendData(UtilityLocatorz.SignUp.USER_PASSWORD);
        util.clickElement(UtilityLocatorz.SignUp.USER_NEWSLETTER);
        Select day = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("days")));
        day.selectByValue("1");
        Select month = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("months")));
        month.selectByValue("2");
        Select year = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("years")));
        year.selectByValue("2014");
        util.sendData(SignUp.USER_COMPANY);
        util.sendData(SignUp.USER_STATE);
        util.sendData(SignUp.USER_ADDRESS1);
        util.sendData(SignUp.USER_MOBILENUMBER);
        util.sendData(SignUp.USER_ZIPCODE);
        util.sendData(SignUp.USER_ALIAS);
        util.sendData(SignUp.USER_CITY);
        util.clickElement(SignUp.SUBMITACCOUNT);
        reportLog("After creating a new account, User will login to his new account");

        boolean  chkElement=driver.findElement(By.className("View my customer account")).isDisplayed();

        Assert.assertTrue(chkElement);
        util.clickElement(SignUp.USER_SIGN_OUT);
        //test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel("PASS", ExtentColor.GREEN));
    }
```

...........................................................................

```
This is the class where my utility methods are being called.
public class UtilityMethods extends ExtentReportBaseClass{

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver openBrowser(String browsers) {

        System.out.println("initiated browser is " + browsers);
        if (browsers.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "");

            DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

            dc.setCapability("marionatte", false);
            FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
            opt.merge(dc);
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);

        }

        else if (browsers.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
            // String driverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") +
            // "\\src\\Drivers\\chromedriver";
            // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }

        return driver;

    }

    public static void launchWebsite(String URL) {
        driver.get(URL);

    }

    public static By locateByElement(String locator, String locatorValue) {
        By by = null;

        switch (locator) {

        case "id":
            by = By.id(locatorValue);
            break;

        case "name":
            by = By.name(locatorValue);

            break;
        case "linktext":
            by = By.linkText(locatorValue);
            break;
        case "partialLinkText":
            by = By.partialLinkText(locatorValue);
            break;

        case "className":
            by = By.className(locatorValue);
            break;

        case "tagName":
            by = By.tagName(locatorValue);
            break;

        case "cssSelector":
            by = By.cssSelector(locatorValue);
            break;

        case "xpath":
            by = By.xpath(locatorValue);
            break;

        }

        System.out.println("value of by is" + by);
        return by;

    }

    public void sendDataById(String locatorValue, String userData) {

        driver.findElement(By.id(locatorValue)).sendKeys(userData);

    }

    public void sendData(String element) {
        String[] var = element.split("###");

        String loctype = var[0];
        String locval = var[1];
        // System.out.println(locval);
        String uservalue = var[2];
        // System.out.println(locval);
        // System.out.println(uservalue);

        By locator = locateByElement(loctype, locval);
        System.out.println(loctype);
        System.out.println(locval);
        driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(uservalue);

    }

    public  WebDriver getdriver() {
        if (driver == null) {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            return driver;
        } else {
            return driver;
        }
    }



    public void clickElement(String locElem) throws IOException {

        try {

            System.out.println(locElem);
            String[] var = locElem.split("###");
            String loctype = var[0];
            String locval = var[1];
            System.out.println(loctype);
            System.out.println(locval);
            By locator = locateByElement(loctype, locval);

            driver.findElement(locator).click();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Catched Exception, Element not clicked is" + locElem);

        }
    }
```

//////// Stack Trace......

```
Cannot instantiate class TestCases.LoginTestCase
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:336)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:190)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:81)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:73)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:38)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:389)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:192)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:713)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:24)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Utility.UtilityMethods.<init>(UtilityMethods.java:19)
    at Utility.ExtentReportBaseClass.<init>(ExtentReportBaseClass.java:25)
    at Utility.UtilityMethods.<init>(UtilityMethods.java:19)
    at Utility.ExtentReportBaseClass.<init>(ExtentReportBaseClass.java:25)
    at Utility.UtilityMethods.<init>(UtilityMethods.java:19)
    at Utility.ExtentReportBaseClass.<init>(ExtentReportBaseClass.java:25)
    at Utility.UtilityMethods.<init>(UtilityMethods.java:19)
    at Utility.ExtentReportBaseClass.<init>(ExtentReportBaseClass.java:25)
    at Utility.UtilityMethods.<init>(UtilityMethods.java:19)
    at Utility.ExtentReportBaseClass.<init>(ExtentReportBaseClass.java:25)
```

Comment: is this a typo: `"marionatte"`?

Comment: No it is a separate webdriver that come with geckodriver, It is used here to resolve compatibility issue.

Comment: _don't know in which line in my code causing these errors_: It's simple, just look at the stacktrace. There you will see the relevant class names and line numbers.

Comment: I have seen but didn't find the reason in those lines for the error to come.

Comment: @RohnKerry Segregate the two errors. Asking for help for one error at a time will help the contributors to solve the issues faster.

Comment: @RohnKerry Can you update the question with the _error stack trace_ so that at-least we can have an idea which line causing the problem.

Comment: you have a stack overflow caused by two methods calling each other. (`UtilityMethods:19` and `ExtendReportBaseClass:25`).  Just put a breakpoint at either place and see why they are doing that.

Comment: Both are marked with `<init>`, so the problem is with construction. Probably the (implicit?) constructor of `ExtentReportBaseClass` causes an attempt to create an instance of its own child `UtilityMethods` (which in turn implicitly invokes its super constructor, etc.)

Comment: So what is the solution?